# PreferenceScreen android:paddingTop not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, preferencefragment

With normal layout file, I can set padding top like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"

>
```

However, with preference screen, it renders the padding short of some pixels (the action bar is 168 dp, but the padding appears only 144), any idea how to fix this cross-device way. Thanks.

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `PreferenceScreen` you don't have access to those xml attributes. But what you can do is add this attribute to it:

```
android:layout="@layout/header_setting"
```

Then create a XML layout file called in this example "header_settings" you can change the sizes and padding as normal. But applying the id's to the elements the PreferenceScreen knows where the titles goes or icon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+android:id/icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

    <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And now here is an example on how the PreferenceScreen should look like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout="@layout/pref_screen">


    <PreferenceCategory>
        <PreferenceScreen
            android:icon="@drawable/setting_star"
            android:layout="@layout/header_setting"
            android:title="Upgrade to Pro!">

        </PreferenceScreen>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Notice how you only have access to the attributes: title, summary, and icon. The layout attribute lets you customize it to whatever you want to do. In the XML you must keep the id's the same since thats how the PreferenceScreen knows thats were to put the title text or the icon image.

I hope this helps!